# How can I find out what caused my reputation loss?

Tags: discussion, reputation

I'm new to this site. Although I  had made my account almost 6 months ago,  I've started using stackexchange only very recently (about 10-15 days). I'm active particularly on stackexchange mathematics.

The reason why I'm writing this is I want to know in what ways can a person lose reputation on any stackexchange website? I had a reputation of 717 on stackexchange mathematics but the moment I refreshed the page I lost about 20 points and my reputation came down to 697. No-one has downvoted any of my posts.

I do not have any problem with losing reputation but I should like to know where I lost 20 points without any reason?

Comment: Nobody downvoted any of my posts...

Comment: Could be because one or more of the accounts that accepted one of your answers or gave you upvotes have been removed?

Comment: Try checking the "show removed posts" box at the bottom of your reputation history page.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A ,Thanks for addressing my query. One of the questions I had answered has been removed.  Sorry for bothering you... i did not know about this.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A ,you certainly did.